# How to create a backup of database using php script. I am facing a error

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying  this code but it shows a error

> "Could not take data backup:
>
> Can't create/write to file '\transfer\employees.sql' (Errcode: 2)"

when I click on my button to create a backup file.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbdatabase = "ghis_verf";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if(! $conn )
{
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$table_name = "employees";
$backup_file  = "/transfer/employees.sql";
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";
mysql_select_db($dbdatabase,$conn) or die("Cannot select database");
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not take data backup: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Backedup  data successfully\n";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have writing permission in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not have folder `/transfer` at the root of your web server or does not have permissions to write to it.

Make sure you can perform `su -c "touch /transfer/employees.sql" www-data` (replace `www-data` with proper user for you system). If no - check permissions or folder existence.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due insufficient write privilege. If you're using Linux, you may want to create the folder first as a placeholder with sufficient permissions for Apache to write to:

```
$ cd /path/to/app
$ mkdir transfer
$ chmod 777 transfer
```

See if the following PHP script works for you:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbdatabase = "ghis_verf";
$table_name = "employees";
$backup_file = "transfer/employees.sql";
$cmd = "mysqldump -h {$dbhost} -u {$dbusername} -p '{$dbpassword}' {$dbdatabase} {$table_name} > {$backup_file}";
system($cmd);
?>
```

Also `/transfer` is the absolute root path in your file system. Maybe it's something like `/var/www/transfer`? Or change it to absolute path such as `transfer/`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link below to export database via PHP code. Hope this will work for you. 
http://phptipmaster.blogspot.com/2013/01/mysql-database-export-via-php-code.html